# Adjusting a looped arrow SVG file to match the style with other arrows

Tags: inkscape, svg, xml

I'm using an SVG file to depict intra-regional migration flows of people in the Netherlands. Here's what I made so far:

[image]

The looped arrow is the only SVG image here, the other arrows are rendered by other means. As one can see, the looped arrow does not have a black outline (unlike the other arrows). I'd like to make the outline style and color of the arrows uniform.

To that end, I tried adjusting the code of the SVG file, which has been provided to me by Billy Ker ([here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142990/how-to-adjust-an-svg-image-in-such-a-way-that-it-is-modifiable-in-qgis)) and Simbamangu ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379256/how-to-fix-the-placement-of-an-svg-marker-in-qgis)). This is the latter's code, which resizes the former's in such a way that it is viewable in QGIS:

```
<svg width=".1mm" height=".1mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2.1694 2.1665" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g transform="matrix(.1 0 0 .1 .013859 .018301)" fill="none" image-rendering="auto" stroke="#d40000" stroke-width="2.5862">
      <path d="m26.8 13.9a12.8 12.8 0 0 1-10.6 12.6 12.8 12.8 0 0 1-14.3-8.22 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 5.6-15.5 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 16.2 2.81" stop-color="#000000"/>
      <path d="m24.7 0.472-0.434 5.65-5.58-0.401" stop-color="#000000" style="font-variation-settings:normal"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

This renders a static image of a loop. In order to make it dynamic, I used information from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro/77421#77421) GIS.SE question to make its colors and outlines modifiable in QGIS. Here's the adjusted code:

```
<svg width=".1mm" height=".1mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 3.1694 3.1665" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g transform="matrix(.1 0 0 .1 .013859 .018301)" fill="none" image-rendering="auto" stroke="#d40000" stroke-width="3.0862">
  <path d="m26.8 13.9a12.8 12.8 0 0 1-10.6 12.6 12.8 12.8 0 0 1-14.3-8.22 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 5.6-15.5 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 16.2 2.81" stop-color="#000000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 50" stroke="param(outline) #000" fill="param(fill) #FFF"/>
  <path d="m24.7 0.472-0.434 5.65-5.58-0.401" stop-color="#000000" fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

However, this code creates the follow loop:

[image]

So then I removed the

```
fill="param(fill) #FFF"
```

parts of both paths, to obtain:

[image]

Unfortunately, I now can't change the color of the arrows anymore. So instead, I changed the code to:

```
<svg width=".1mm" height=".1mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 3.1694 3.1665" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g transform="matrix(.1 0 0 .1 .013859 .018301)" fill="none" image-rendering="auto" stroke="#d40000" stroke-width="3.0862">
  <path d="m26.8 13.9a12.8 12.8 0 0 1-10.6 12.6 12.8 12.8 0 0 1-14.3-8.22 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 5.6-15.5 12.8 12.8 0 0 1 16.2 2.81"  stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 40"/>
  <path d="m24.7 0.472-0.434 5.65-5.58-0.401" fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="1"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

This is somewhat better. However, it's still not quite what I'm after, because when I now change the stroke color to black, this is what it looks like:

[image]

I can adjust the stroke width, but then I get a very thin arrow, instead of a thin outline of the arrow.

What I would like is to have code for the looped arrow that make it look similar to the other (non-looped) arrows in the image. So preferably, the loop would have:

- A thin black outline of the whole arrow;
- A modifiable arrow width that is proportionate with the size of the arrow head;
- The arrow starting off slightly less wide, and getting a bit wider towards the end, like the other arrows

**Question** do you know how I could change the code of the SVG file of the looped arrow in such a way that it satisfies the properties listed above? (The first two properties are the most important, the third one is perhaps somewhat more difficult and slightly less essential, but it would be nice to have.)

Comment: Can you not merely *draw* the arrow you want in Inkscape and save it as SVG? Why *must* you edit an existing SVG? And more over.. why must you edit the XML of the SVG?

Comment: @Scott I could try, but I have never used Inkscape or a comparable program. I'm afraid it would take me a long time.

Comment: Might take you longer to try and suss out the edits in XML.

Comment: @Scott Maybe. I just hope this is a relatively easy task - either by changing the XML or drawing the arrow - for someone over here with a lot of experience and knowledge of SVG files and/or Inkscape. I will also give credits to the people who gave answers to this question and related ones in the article I intend to write about it. My background in graphic design is very limited. It's probably a good idea for me to learn more about it for future projects, but for now I hope someone could help me out.

Comment: @Scott Also: my version of Inkscape keeps breaking down on my (Mac) computer. And XML code snippets like * fill="param(fill) #FFF" * allow the image to be modifiable in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

In Inkscape, you can select both paths, and do *Path > Stroke to path*.

This will convert the strokes to outlines, with a fill.

[image]

Next, do *Path > Union*.  This is a boolean operation which will merge the two paths to one solid shape - i.e. a single closed path with a fill.

[image]

Now you can apply a coloured fill, and a thin black stroke to get the effect you want.

[image]

Here's an example of the cleaned up SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="28.1mm" height="28mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 28.1 28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g fill="#ff7f2a" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".159">
<path d="m13.9.08c-.747.00716-1.5.0746-2.24.203-1.58.274-3.14.828-4.6 1.67v-.00207c-5.85 3.39-8.42 10.5-6.09 16.9 2.31 6.35 8.88 10.1 15.5 8.93 6.65-1.16 11.5-6.95 11.5-13.7l-2.23-.0021c-.0041 5.68-4.08 10.5-9.68 11.5h-.0062c-5.61 1.01-11.1-2.15-13.1-7.5v-.0042c-1.97-5.34.187-11.3 5.11-14.2 4.27-2.48 9.53-1.98 13.2 1.05l-2.54-.181-.16 2.22 6.69.48.519-6.76-2.22-.17-.248 3.22c-2.65-2.43-6.09-3.7-9.56-3.67z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you yet again!

Comment: Is there -- in this case -- also an XML-parameter that can control for the thickness of the arrow and the arrow head?

Comment: No, not after you have outlined the arrow. It's no longer a stroke, but a path with an outside stroke, and a fill inside.

Comment: This edit is destructive, so if you need to do it, make a copy of the original should you ever need a thicker arrow.

Comment: @MaxMuller - sorry, forgot to add your name to these comments.

Comment: That's okay. Thank you. I'm still thinking about how the arrow path could be made thicker and thinner inside QGIS. If you have any ideas on that, could you please let me know?

Comment: It seems that something akin to what I have in mind can be done by changing the "outset" of a path, see 10:18 of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGFp4EoJi9g . Do you know whether that is a parameter that can be made modifiable via QGIS by adjusting the path in the XML?

Comment: @MaxMuller There is an Dynamic Offet, and Offset Path Effect in Inkscape, but these aren't part of the SVG format itself. When saving an optimized SVG from Inkscape these will be changed back into unalterable paths again.  If you save an Inkscape SVG containing Inkscapes own XML, will keep the outset effects as editable, but outside of Inkscape these are unlikely to work in another application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116344/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-max-muller).